# Puzzled by a method that runs in many places, but not in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios

In one of my view controllers, I have a method called

```
-(void)calculateUpdatedTotal{ // do things here }
```

Every time a user leaves a text field, of which there are many, I run the update and the statement looks like this:

```
[self calculateUpdatedTotal];
```

It works great, except as described below.

I need to have the calculations updated when the controller view appears, so in my viewDidAppear method, I included the statement that calls the method.   viewDidAppear is running as intended, but [self calculateUpdatedTotal]; is doing nothing.  No errors, and no warnings.  I’ve used several NSLog statements to narrow it down, and everything is ok, except that it’s not running. Could it have something to do with viewDidAppear?  Any thoughts on how to track down and fix the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: At runtime, it is not entering `calculateUpdatedTotal` when invoked from `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: viewWillAppear would likely be a better choice since this is called just BEFORE the view appears

Comment: The answer to Dan's question is yes.   I'll move it to to viewWillAppear and see if it gets invoked.  Thank you.

Comment: moving it to viewWillAppear did not get it running.  I also tried running setNeedsDisplay just after the call to calculateUpdatedTotal, and nothing there either.  Guess I need to find a work-around. Or there may be some other problem affecting it.

Comment: trace in a debugger the iOS call to viewDidAppear, then do a "STEP INTO" on the call to [self calculateUpdatedTotal]

Comment: How do you expect people to help with this? **You're** puzzled and you have the full code in front of you. We can only speculate until you show us some more code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you did not put a call in either viewWillLoad or view WillUnload to verify those routines are called. Assuming this code is in a UIViewController subclass with a nib and a view, the only possible explanation is you typed in the method names and did not use command competion or copy paste. That is verify you have:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

I have never ever heard of a case where these did not get called by the system. However, if you misspell the name, you'll never know since its not a protocol forcing you to provide such methods.